# Squirrel-SQL throws class not found exception

Tags: squirrel-sql

I am running Squirrel-SQL version 3.9.0 using JDK 10 on MS-Windows 10. I have configured the Microsoft SQL server JDBC driver sqljdbc42.jar along with it's native DDLs to enable native kerberos authentication. But when I try to connect to my database, I get the message `JDBC Driver class not found class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. How do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by placing the [jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar) into `squirrel-sql-3.9.0/lib` folder and restarting the application.

Comment: This fix has been verified to work with SquirrelSQL 4.0 on JDK 12.

Comment: This fix also works for squirrel-sql 3.9+ on JDK 11

Answer (score 0):

had same problem . i updgrated everything to last version of Squirel 4.5.1 (janvier 2023) & last JDK 19 & last driver SqlServer , but problem continue to occur

i found another post on StackOverflow who asked which repository had this jaxb jar
[How do I resolve Could not find artifact javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:pom:2.3.0-b161121.1438 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72128029/how-do-i-resolve-could-not-find-artifact-javax-xml-bindjaxb-apipom2-3-0-b1611)

this is the link to jaxb jar, i added it in lib/ under squirell directory , then it worked
[https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav~javax.xml.bind~jaxb-api~2.3.0-b161121.1438~](https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav%7Ejavax.xml.bind%7Ejaxb-api%7E2.3.0-b161121.1438%7E)~